# Makefile - wildcard, how to do that properly?

Tags: c++, c, makefile

```
FLAGS:= -Wall -Wvla -g -lm
OBJECT := Nominated.h UniversityNominated.h AliceGraduate.h BobGraduate.h CollegeNominated.h ColinGraduate.h DannyGraduate.h NominatedList.h Parser.h Parser.cpp
all: Hire

Nominated.o: Nominated.h Nominated.cpp
    g++ -c $(FLAGS) Nominated.cpp -o Nominated.o

NominatedList.o: Nominated.h NominatedList.h NominatedList.cpp
    g++ -c $(FLAGS) NominatedList.cpp -o NominatedList.o

UniversityNominated.o: Nominated.h UniversityNominated.h UniversityNominated.cpp
    g++ -c $(FLAGS) UniversityNominated.cpp -o UniversityNominated.o

AliceGraduate.o: Nominated.h UniversityNominated.h AliceGraduate.h AliceGraduate.cpp
    g++ -c $(FLAGS) AliceGraduate.cpp -o AliceGraduate.o

BobGraduate.o: Nominated.h UniversityNominated.h BobGraduate.h BobGraduate.cpp
    g++ -c $(FLAGS) BobGraduate.cpp -o BobGraduate.o

CollegeNominated.o: Nominated.h CollegeNominated.h CollegeNominated.cpp
    g++ -c $(FLAGS) CollegeNominated.cpp -o CollegeNominated.o

ColinGraduate.o: Nominated.h CollegeNominated.h ColinGraduate.h ColinGraduate.cpp
    g++ -c $(FLAGS) ColinGraduate.cpp -o ColinGraduate.o

DannyGraduate.o: Nominated.h CollegeNominated.h DannyGraduate.h DannyGraduate.cpp
    g++ -c $(FLAGS) DannyGraduate.cpp -o DannyGraduate.o

Parser.o: $(OBJECT)  
    g++ -c $(FLAGS) Parser.cpp -o Parser.o

Parser: Nominated.o UniversityNominated.o AliceGraduate.o BobGraduate.o CollegeNominated.o ColinGraduate.o DannyGraduate.o NominatedList.o Parser.o
    ar rcu libParser.a Nominated.o UniversityNominated.o AliceGraduate.o BobGraduate.o CollegeNominated.o ColinGraduate.o DannyGraduate.o NominatedList.o Parser.o
    ranlib libParser.a

Hire: Hire.cpp Parser
    g++ Hire.cpp libParser.a -o Hire

clean:
    rm -f Hire *.a *.o *~
.PHONY: clean all
```

so this is my Makefile.

How can I make less ugly ?

I am always read about that but I can not get the idea

How ?

I mean I understand I need to use the wildcard tool but as you I probably used it wrong

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example of how to use wildcard and pattern substitution:

```
SOURCES := $(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJECTS := $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(SOURCES))
CXX := g++ -Wall -Wvla -g

.cpp.o:
        ${CXX} -c $<
```

This will build all the .cpp files into their object files.

Comment: but what about the headers ? I do not need need to use them in my makefile ?

Comment: Your compiler should have a -MM option to generate dependencies.

Answer (score 4):

There's many things you can do, but one of the best is a [pattern rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern) for specific types.  All of your objects seem to be built the same way.

```
%.o: %.cpp
    ${CXX} -c $(FLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

You'll notice that this doesn't include any header files as dependencies.  Manually maintaining the header dependencies in a Makefile is a bad idea because it's bound to get out of date as you modify your program.  Sometimes your compiler can generate make-friendly dependencies for you automatically.  Assuming you have a list of objects such as this:

```
OBJS := $(SOURCES:%.c=%.o)
```

You can include this at the very end of your Makefile (with no blank line afterward)

```
-include $(OBJS:.o=.d)
```

Then add, `-MMD` to your compiler flags.  This will cause GCC to generate .d files that contain the header dependencies for each of your objects as a Make rule, and the above include line will include those rules and use them to resolve the dependencies of your objects.  This will mean that any header change will cause all files that include it (directly or indirectly) to be rebuilt.

Comment: I am very sorry, but I did not understand. if I have to include the header file' How can I do it ?

Comment: @John, he means that if your source files depend on any other files, like header files (and they normally do), you can use GCC to do automatic dependency generation.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
FLAGS   = -Wall -Wextra
SRC     = $(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJ     = $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(SRC))
DEP     = $(patsubst %.cpp,%.d,$(SRC))
PARSER  = $(filter-out Hire.o,$(OBJ))

all: $(DEP) build

build:
    make Hire

%.d:
    g++ -MM $*.cpp > $*.d

%.o: %.cpp
    g++ $(FLAGS) -c $*.cpp

libParser.a: $(PARSER)
    ar rcu libParser.a $(PARSER)
    ranlib libParser.a

Hire: Hire.cpp libParser.a
    g++ Hire.cpp libParser.a -o Hire

clean:
    rm -f Hire *.a *.o *.d *~

.PHONY: clean all 

#
# This line includes all the dependencies.
# There is one for each file.
# Check the *.d files after you run make
-include $(DEP)
```